# Multiplas conexões com Socket PHP para receber mensagens HTTP e salvar no MySQL

Tags: php, linux, socket, centos

Preciso configurar uma porta no meu servidor dedicado que roda o SO CentOs 6.10 kvm, para que ela receba mensagens (geolocalização) de alguns rastreadores via TCP (IP:PORTA), e salve esses dados no banco de dados MySQL através da conexão de um script PHP.

**O que já foi feito:**

1) abri a porta TCP `49100` usando o *terminal* com os seguintes comandos:

```
> iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 49100 -j ACCEPT
> iptables -nL |grep 49100
# ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:49100
```

2) Utilizei um script PHP para conectar à porta e aceitar múltiplas conexões.

**server.php**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting
 * as it comes in. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = getHostByName(getHostName()); //IP LOCAL;
$port = 49100;

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "<br>";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "<br>";
}

if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "<br>";
}

do {
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
        echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "<br>";
        break;
    }
    /* Send instructions. */
    $msg = "<br>Welcome to the PHP Test Server. <br>" .
        "To quit, type 'quit'. To shut down the server type 'shutdown'.<br>";
    socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));

    do {
        if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
            echo "socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "<br>";
            break 2;
        }
        if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($buf == 'quit') {
            break;
        }
        if ($buf == 'shutdown') {
            socket_close($msgsock);
            break 2;
        }
        $talkback = "PHP: You said '$buf'.<br>";
        socket_write($msgsock, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
        echo "$buf<br>";
    } while (true);
    socket_close($msgsock);
} while (true);

socket_close($sock);
?>
```

**client.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$host = getHostByName(getHostName()); //IP LOCAL;
$port = 49100;
// No Timeout 
set_time_limit(0);

/* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting
 * as it comes in. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$message = 'Olá, mundo!';

//Create Socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");

//Connect to the server
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect toserver\n");

//Write to server socket
socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");

//Read the response from the server
$result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
echo "Reply From Server  :" . $result;

//Close socket
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Abri o navegador e abri server.php e client.php, nessa ordem.

client.php retornou:

> Reply From Server : Welcome to the PHP Test Server.  To quit, type
>   'quit'. To shut down the server type 'shutdown'.

server.php retornou:

> Warning: socket_read(): unable to read from socket [104]: Connection
>   reset by peer in /home/usuario/public_html/server.php on line 37
>   socket_read() failed: reason: Connection reset by peer

---

O processo de abertura da porta 49100, aparentemente foi bem sucedida.
Fico com as seguintes questões:

1) *O que está causando esse Warning no server.php?*

2) *Como posso associar a porta 49100 ao script PHP para que toda conexão feita por essa porta execute o script e receba os dados enviados?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que assim que o cliente recebe a mensagem de boas vindas do servidor ele está executando a função socket_close e encerrando a conexão.

Desta forma, quando o servidor tenta enviar uma segunda mensagem ao cliente a conexão já foi encerrada.

O que você deve fazer é utilizar um while no seu cliente para que ele fique esperando a resposta do servidor, em vez de fechar a conexão.

Ou seja, tanto cliente como servidor precisam estar em um while para poder enviar varias mensagens um ao outro... somente após a última mensagem é que o cliente deve encerrar o while e fechar a conexão.

Comment: Entendi, faz sentido. Mas sabe me dizer como posso deixar esse script do server.php aguardando por mensagens "a todo momento"? Tipo associar ele à porta, e então quando a porta é acessada ele executa e recebe os dados. Porque o cliente vai ser um hardware acessando IP e Porta...

Comment: Mas o seu servidor já está fazendo isso. Perceba que a mensagem que o servidor te retorna é apenas um warning, ou seja, um aviso... O cliente fechou a conexão mas o servidor continua rodando esperando novas conexões. Experimente iniciar vários clientes em sequência se conectando nesse servidor. Os clientes vão receber a mensagem é fechar, mas o servidor vai continuar rodando.

Comment: Mas por exemplo, no código da pergunta ele só executou porque eu abri server.php e o deixe esperando pelo cliente. Se eu abrir somente o client.php ele não conecta, pois o server.php está parado.. (socket_connect(): unable to connect [111]: Connection refused). Fazendo uma conexão remota, não será possível rodar o server manualmente.

Comment: Posso adicionar o script como um serviço no servidor :) http://www.funphp.com/2010/12/01/create-a-socket-server-in-php-and-run-as-a-service/

Comment: De fato, na minha resposta e nos comentários quando eu escrevi “servidor” eu estava o tempo todo me referindo ao “server.php”. O server.php precisa estar rodando ativo no servidor Web para que os clientes (no seu caso, “client.php”) se conectem.